# ADCS Subordinate CA: does the domain automatically trust the root

Tags: active-directory, certificate-authority, active-directory-adcs

I created a subordinate "enterprise" CA server using ADCS on an active directory domain.  The root CA that signed this subordinate CA's cert is not part of the windows domain.

Q1: Does the active directory domain automatically trust the root CA that signed the subordinate CA's cert?  Microsoft ADCS has access to this root CA cert (when I loaded the signed subordinate cert into the CA) and there is no reason for ADCS to *not* send the cert out to all domain members.

Q2: If not, what is the canonical/proper way to get the domain members to trust the root CA?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to export the root CA certificate (to a USB stick if the ROOT CA is - hopefully - not network connected). You then need to publish the certificate to AD using certutil -dspublish RootCACertificate RootCA. Once this is done, all domain-joined computers will get the certificate added to their list of Trusted Root Certification Authorities and should then start to trust your subordinate CAs.

Comment: There should be no need to export or put the root ca cert on a USB stick, etc.  The root CA cert should be readily available from the cert chain on the subordinate CA.

Comment: Where is `certutil -dspublish RootCACertificate RootCA` maintained?  Where can I see a list of all certs I've "published" via that mechanism?  How can I "un-publish" a cert that was previously published using that mechanism?  I would have imagined that GPO would be the canonical way to publish a cert... where I can edit/delete/view what I've done.